# Как получить данные из excel таблицы в telegram bot

Tags: excel, telegram, google-spreadsheet

В организации каждую неделю заказываюся обеды на каждого сотрудника. 
Имеется excel таблица, где столбцы соответствуют фамилии сотрудников организации. Строки это блюда. На пересечении единички, означающие что конкретное блюдо заказал конкретный человек.

Когда приходишь  разогревать еду приходиться долго искать себя в таблице. Хотелось бы сразу получать выборку "Сотрудник-еда" в телеграмме.

Сам имею не большой опыт. Пока думаю над концепцией.  Пока идея такая 
excel таблица==>json==>google таблицы==> запросы бота в гугл таблицу. 
Обновлять данные надо раз в день.

Подскажите как проще получить данные из экселевской таблицы в телеграмм

Comment: В программировании одна из важных вещей -- это избавляться от излишних шагов, не программировать/автоматизировать лишнее. Попробуйте объяснить, почему в вашем концепте нельзя сразу вести таблицу в гугле таблице, а нужно сделать эксель локлально -> нечто -> гугл таблица. По мне -- это лишние шаги. Возможно, это нет так, но если так -- тогда вам нужно выбирать язык программирования бота и пробовать делать запросы к гуглтаблицам. И ваш вопрос нужно закрыть как слишком общий: вы понимаете, что из гугл таблицы бот уже должен забирать данные, но не указываете язык программирования. Слишком общо.

Comment: Закрывать не хотелось бы ибо не получу ответа. Надо дополнить. Язык программирования должен быть такой, где больше примеров реализаций ботов. Я полагаю это javascript. Хранить данные сразу в гугл таблице не получиться, ибо это организационный вопрос не в моем ведении. Прошу помочь ибо  гугл мне ответов не дал на вопрос как из гугл таблиц данные получать в бота. П.С. где копать? Что смотреть?